# Spherical co-ordinates are not canonical?

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

One of the conditions for canonical transformations is that all momentum variables should commute. But $(L_x ,L_y)=L_z \neq 0$. Does that mean these are not canonical co ordinates? But aren't point transformations a special case of canonical transformations? How can these transformations be point but not canonical?

EDIT- Spherical co-ordinates are $(r, \theta, \phi)$. The momenta corresponding to $\theta$ and $\phi$ are $L_x$ and $L_z$. They don't commute as I already wrote.

By point transformations, I mean the co ordinate transformations in the Lagrangian formalism. But even disregarding that, we use spherical co-ordinates all the time in Hamiltonian and Quantum mechanics. They can't be non-canonical, right?

Comment: How did you find the momentum corresponding to $\theta$? Your conclusion that it's $L_x$ looks wrong.

Comment: @Ruslan I wrote them backwards sorry. $\theta$ has $L_z$ as it rotates about the $z$ axis.

Comment: Regardless of naming, only one angle has a well-defined axis: the one that rotates around $\hat e_z$. The other angle is that of a standing spherical wave along (and into) the $z$-axis, and if you find corresponding momentum, it won't coincide with any of Cartesian components of angular momentum.

Comment: @Ruslan Do you know of the other momentum? Why doesn't it have a popular name?

Comment: I don't know what it's called. I suppose it doesn't have much use because the interpretation of the variable is not so enlightening, nor are such states with $|m|\ll \ell$ very relevant to the classical limit.

Comment: @Ruslan But it's a conserved quantity. Can't we construct a simultaneous eigenbasis of $L_z$, $H$ and this unnamed momentum? Instead, we do that with $L_z$, $H$ and $L^2$.

Comment: Is it? I wouldn't be so sure...

Comment: @Ruslan  It is. $V$ is just a function of $r$ after all.

Comment: $V$ being a function of $r$ only results in $L_x$, $L_y$, $L_z$ and combinations thereof being conserved. Can we form $mr^2\dot\theta$ (with $\theta$ being zenith angle) from them? (I really don't know, maybe we can, but it should be proved.)

Comment: @Ruslan We don't have to do that. From the Euler Lagrange equations (assuming $L=T-V$), it can be proven that if $V$ doesn't depend on any variable (in this case $\theta$ and $\phi$), the corresponding momenta are conserved.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. From Euler-Lagrange equation, even assuming a free particle, we have $\frac{d}{dt} p_\theta=\frac m2r^2\sin(2\theta)\dot\varphi^2,$ which makes no sense if $p_\theta=\mathrm{const}.$ Besides, [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/659519/21441) gives an explicit expression for $p_\theta$ in terms of $L_i$, which is not free of coordinates, which corroborates my doubt in conservation of $p_\theta.$

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah, I didn't think it'd show its face in the kinetic energy term. But the kinetic energy does depend on $\theta$

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459424/partition-function-in-spherical-coordinates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Spherical co-ordinates are $(r,\theta,\phi)$. The momenta corresponding to $\theta$ and $\phi$ are $L_x$ and $L_z$.

No they aren't. It's true that $p_\phi=L_z$, but $p_\theta= \cos(\phi) L_y - \sin(\phi) L_x$.

---

The free-particle Lagrangian in spherical coordinates is
$$L = \frac{1}{2} m\big(\dot r^2 + r^2\dot \theta^2 + r^2\sin^2(\theta) \dot \phi^2\big)$$
$$\implies \pmatrix{p_\theta \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot\theta} = mr^2\dot \theta\\p_\phi \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \phi} = mr^2\sin^2(\theta) \dot \phi}$$

Recall that
$$L_x = m(y \dot z - z \dot y) = m r^2\big(-\dot \theta \sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)- \dot \phi\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) - \dot \theta \cos^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)\big)$$
$$= -mr^2\big(\dot \theta \sin(\phi) + \dot \phi \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\big)$$
$$L_y= m(z\dot x - x\dot z)= mr^2(\dot \theta \cos^2(\theta) \cos(\phi) - \dot \phi \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) + \dot \theta\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\phi)\big)$$
$$= mr^2\big(\dot \theta \cos(\phi) -\dot \phi \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)\big)$$
$$\implies -\sin(\phi)L_x + \cos(\phi)L_y = mr^2\dot\theta = p_\theta$$
as promised.

---

The Poisson bracket of the two angular momentum coordinates is then

$$\{p_\theta,p_\phi\} = \{\cos(\phi)L_y,L_z\} - \{\sin(\phi) L_x,L_z\}$$
Noting that $\{AB,C\}=A\{B,C\}+\{A,C\}B$ and that $\{f(\phi),L_z\} = \{f(\phi),p_\phi\} = f'(\phi)$, we quickly find that $\{p_\theta,p_\phi\}=0$ as expected.